# Creating map showing my data usingplotGoogleMaps

Tags: r, plotgooglemaps

I am trying to plot points on a map using R and plotGoogleMaps. I have a dataframe that I am attempting to use but I can not figure out how to do it.

My code is:

`df <- data.frame(dbGetQuery(con, paste('select * from googlemaps')))`

An example of the out to this is:

```
      T1141      LAT       LNG
1     A/BCD 51.48503 -0.062313
2     B/CDE 51.56495 -0.078709
3     C/DEF 51.54829 -0.0469517
```

The next code I use is this:
`coordinates(df) <- ~LAT+LNG`

But this gives me the following error:

`Error in .checkNumericCoerce2double(obj) : 
  cannot retrieve coordinates from non-numeric elements`

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

I tried checking the mode of the column as suggested in the comment and this was the result:

`coordinates(df) <- ~LAT+LNG
Error in .checkNumericCoerce2double(obj) :
  cannot retrieve coordinates from non-numeric elements`

`mode(df$LAT)
[1] "numeric"`

`mode(df$LNG)
[1] "numeric"`

Comment: Have you tried checking the type of the LAT and LNG columns?  From the error it looks like they should be numeric but maybe they are stored as factors or strings in `df`.  Try `mode(df$LAT)` or `mode(df$LNG)` to check.  If it is a character or factor use `as.numeric` to do the conversion.

Comment: @av1 sorry for the slow reply ... I tried what you suggested and this was my results: `> coordinates(df) <- ~LAT+LNG
Error in .checkNumericCoerce2double(obj) : 
  cannot retrieve coordinates from non-numeric elements
> mode(df$LAT)
[1] "numeric"
> mode(df$LNG)
[1] "numeric"

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example with the real or toy data?